# PHP: Replace Extra White Space Between People's Names With a Comma

Tags: php

I need to clean up some strings from my database. I happen to have text with pairs of people's names that contain extra white space and breaks between them.

I'm using this code but it is too aggressive:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\s+#', ',', trim($str));
```

where  $str can be:

```
    $str =`Frank Smith        
                               John Belushi`
```

The result should be a string with pairs of names delimited by a comma, as follows:

"Frank Smith,John Belushi"

Comment: This is not a duplicate; I know b/c I looked at the so-called duplicate answer.  It is a different question and unfortunately the "closer(s)" missed the nuance.  I think in all fairness it should be reopened, esp. since I would like to post my answer which is different but workable, too.  For the curious, you can check it out at: https://3v4l.org/3YZIn

Answer (score 1):

it may be a duplicate but the correct answer is

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ',', str_replace("\n", " ", $str)));
```

Comment: What about https://3v4l.org/00UCc.  If you replace newline with empty string then you could eliminate trim().  Does that work?